# Failed to read data from Bigtable using Google's canonical example

Tags: python, google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

I'm following Google's advice for [writing a single row of data to Bigtable](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/writing-data#simple) and then [reading it back again](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/reading-data#single-row).

Hence my code looks like this:

```py
import datetime

from google.cloud import bigtable


def write_simple(project_id, instance_id, table_id):
    client = bigtable.Client(project=project_id, admin=True)
    instance = client.instance(instance_id)
    table = instance.table(table_id)

    timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    column_family_id = "stats_summary"

    row_key = "phone#4c410523#20190501"

    row = table.direct_row(row_key)
    row.set_cell(column_family_id,
                 "connected_cell",
                 1,
                 timestamp)
    row.set_cell(column_family_id,
                 "connected_wifi",
                 1,
                 timestamp)
    row.set_cell(column_family_id,
                 "os_build",
                 "PQ2A.190405.003",
                 timestamp)

    row.commit()

    print('Successfully wrote row {}.'.format(row_key))

def read_row(project_id, instance_id, table_id):
    client = bigtable.Client(project=project_id, admin=True)
    instance = client.instance(instance_id)
    table = instance.table(table_id)

    row_key = "phone#4c410523#20190501"

    row = table.read_row(row_key)
    print(row)

def print_row(row):
    print("Reading data for {}:".format(row.row_key.decode('utf-8')))
    for cf, cols in sorted(row.cells.items()):
        print("Column Family {}".format(cf))
        for col, cells in sorted(cols.items()):
            for cell in cells:
                labels = " [{}]".format(",".join(cell.labels)) \
                    if len(cell.labels) else ""
                print(
                    "\t{}: {} @{}{}".format(col.decode('utf-8'),
                                            cell.value.decode('utf-8'),
                                            cell.timestamp, labels))
    print("")

write_simple(
    project_id="msm-groupdata-datalake-dev", 
    instance_id="jamiet-dp-tf-instance", 
    table_id="user-agent")
read_row(
    project_id="myproject", 
    instance_id="myinstance", 
    table_id="mytable")
```

When I run it, this is the output I get:

> Successfully wrote row phone#4c410523#20190501.
> None

Its the **None** that is bothering me. Given I am reading/writing the same row_key I would expect to get a row back, but it seems I am not and I don't know why. Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code I think that the issue of why when you read the response is `None` is because you are not actually writing in your table.

You need to check what is your `column_family_id` so you can write the information in the table that you created, for example I made a table for testing and my `column_family_id` was `nf1` and not `stats_summary`.

Best regards.

Comment: Absolutely correct, thank you. Once I created the column family it started working.